# Do ember.js class-based helpers remove observers?

Tags: ember.js

I've got a simple class-based helper in ember that adds an observer to call `.recompute` whenever the property changes.  Since there is no opportunity to call `removeObserver` (as there is no destroy... method on helpers), will continued use of the helper accumulate observer 'cruft' over time and cause a performance leak?

Here is the code: the helper enables grabbing a service or a property on it right in a template instead of having to put the service into the component or controller code behind the template:

```
export default Ember.Helper.extend({
    someService: Ember.inject.service(),
    compute: function([propName]) {
        const svc = this.get('svc');
        if (Ember.isPresent(propName)) {
            svc.addObserver(propName, this, 'recompute');
        }
        return propName ? get(svc, propName) : svc;
    },
});
```

Comment: what is that `svc` ?.  if possible define observer like described [here](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Helper.html#method_recompute)

Comment: Ember.Helper is child of Ember.Object so you should be able to use willDestroy hook.